# Numpy reshape acts different on copied vs. uncopied arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I've come across seemingly inconsistent results when flattening certain numpy arrays with numpy.reshape. Sometimes if I reshape an array it returns a 2D array with one row, whereas if I first copy the array then do the exact same operation, it returns a 1D array.

This seems to happen primarily when combining numpy arrays with scipy arrays, and creates alignment problems when I want to later multiply the flattened array by a matrix.

For example, consider the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sps

n = 10
A = np.random.randn(n,n)
I = sps.eye(n)
X = I+A

x1 = np.reshape(X, -1)
x2 = np.reshape(np.copy(X), -1)

print 'x1.shape=', x1.shape
print 'x2.shape=', x2.shape
```

When run it prints:

```
x1.shape= (1, 100)
x2.shape= (100,)
```

The same thing happens with numpy.flatten(). What is going on here? Is this behavior intentional?

Comment: This was a puzzle until I constructed `X` as you did, and I looked at the result.  It printed as `matrix`, not `array`.  You should have included a `print X` (possibly for `n=3`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You added together a sparse matrix object and a normal ndarray:

```
X = I+A
```

The result is a dense *matrix* object, an instance of `np.matrix`, not a normal ndarray.

This:

```
np.reshape(X, -1)
```

ends up returning a matrix, which can't be less than 2D.

This:

```
np.reshape(np.copy(X), -1)
```

makes a normal ndarray in `np.copy(X)`, so you get a 1D output from `np.reshape`.

Be very careful at all times about whether you're dealing with sparse matrices, dense matrices, or standard ndarrays. Avoid `np.matrix` whenever possible.